# OSGI runtime inside traditional Java EE server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, osgi, modularity

I understand it should probably be other way round (OSGI runtime hosting Java EE servers), as it is [apparently already possible with glassfish.](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_127_embedding_glassfish_in)

However, our clients have extensive experience in administering traditional Java EE servers and significant investment (licenses, training etc.)
Our architecture would benefit from OSGI modular architecture, but I can not ask our clients to switch from Java EE servers to OSGI runtimes.

Is there a way to install OSGI runtime as war or ear inside traditional Java EE servers, even if they will use no container-managed resources (for example thread or connection pools) nor other Java EE features like JNDI, EJB etc?

Our applications use technologies like Hibernate, Spring etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to look at the [bridge servlet](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php) solution from Equinox.
They have a special servlet (bridge servlet) that spawns an OSGi runtime, adds an OSGi HTTP service, and proxies traffic to the HTTP service (and ultimately to your servlets that register themselves to the HTTP service).

Comment: For an example of other people using OSGi in the way you describe: IBM Rational's Jazz server technology(http://www.jazz.net) has been using the bridge servlet mentioned by @sjlee for many years.