# OSGi support at Java EE app servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere, osgi

We've been considering going with OSGi for our web app modules. We are however uncediced on which AS we'd want to use with that.

It seems the native support for OSGi exists in WebSphere and JBoss of the major app servers, and in some a bit less-used ones (such as Glassfish and Geronimo).
For Tomcat or WebLogic it's not directly supported, but through a [bridge workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893494/integrating-equinox-osgi-into-apache-tomcat-web-app).

What features are we giving up for, if we go with Tomcat/WebLogic + workaround?
What would be things that we only would get with a native support such as in JBoss and WebSphere?

One such example seems to be JTA. It doesn't seem we would get Java EE transactions with the bridge workaround. Are there others?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/?

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: I know there are lot of app servers and equivalents out there. Is there some reason I should consider that? Is it somehow different than the ones I've already listed? If so, how?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that you didn't miss it out. More over, I don't think you need any workarounds with Virgo and if you use Spring in your app, Virgo supports it very nicely.

Comment: Another option is Apache Karaf. It supports war deployments as well as wab deployments. So you have all web features and full osgi support.